# systemtap failed to probe the functions. Registration error

Tags: linux-kernel, trace, systemtap, probe

systemtap registration error.

```
WARNING: probe process("/home/user/a.out").function("func").return inode-offset 00000000468ed0c6 registration error (rc -5)
WARNING: probe process("/home/user/a.out").function("func").call inode-offset 00000000468ed0c6 registration error (rc -5)
WARNING: task_finder mmap inode-uprobes callback for task 28532 failed: -5
```

I am learning systemtap. I have a process which calls a function in a while loop. When I start systemtap using "stap -v test.stp" to probe the userspace function, I get the registration error. Following is the complete screen shot;

```
Pass 1: parsed user script and 465 library scripts using 112640virt/48788res/6452shr/42636data kb, in 100usr/20sys/123real ms.
Pass 2: analyzed script: 3 probes, 2 functions, 4 embeds, 3 globals using 114256virt/51968res/7840shr/44252data kb, in 50usr/110sys/162real ms.
Pass 3: using cached /root/.systemtap/cache/66/stap_662fe7689c5fb5d6ef569e8246fa1c8a_3296.c
Pass 4: using cached /root/.systemtap/cache/66/stap_662fe7689c5fb5d6ef569e8246fa1c8a_3296.ko
Pass 5: starting run.
WARNING: probe process("/home/admin/a.out").function("func").return inode-offset 00000000468ed0c6 registration error (rc 0)
WARNING: probe process("/home/admin/a.out").function("func").call inode-offset 00000000468ed0c6 registration error (rc 0)
^CERROR: empty aggregate near operator '@max' at test.stp:6:37
WARNING: Number of errors: 1, skipped probes: 0
WARNING: /usr/bin/staprun exited with status: 1
Pass 5: run completed in 0usr/20sys/9318real ms.
Pass 5: run failed.  [man error::pass5]
```

## test.stp

```
probe process("/home/user/a.out").function("func").return {
  stats <<< gettimeofday_ns() - @entry(gettimeofday_ns())
}
probe end {
  printf("max/avg/min: %d/%d/%d\n", @max(stats), @avg(stats), @min(stats))
  print(@hist_log(stats))
}
global stats
```

## test.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
void func()
{
        printf("Hello\n");
    sleep(1);
}
int main()
{
    while (1)
    {
          func();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

systemtap does not support overlays/union filesystems. The systemtap userspace code has to be changed to get the real inode of a file if it is in overlayfs. For this the systemtap need to be code changed and built. Download systemtap source code make changes in the file `uprobes-inode.c` . The change is to use the `d_backing_inode` to find `inode`. Need to make changes in two places.

```
    inode_1 = d_backing_inode(d_real((struct dentry *) dentry, NULL, 0, 0)); //use inode_1 in the following function.
    if ((vm_flags & VM_EXEC) && !(vm_flags & VM_WRITE))
        rc = stapiu_change_plus(target, task, addr, length,
                    offset, vm_flags, inode_1);
        //          offset, vm_flags, dentry->d_inode);
```

```
    vm_file = stap_find_exe_file(mm);
    if (vm_file) {
        if (vm_file->f_path.dentry)
        {
            //inode = vm_file->f_path.dentry->d_inode;
            inode = d_backing_inode(d_real((struct dentry *) vm_file->f_path.dentry, NULL, 0, 0));
        
        }
        fput(vm_file);
```

Comment: so what should we do to fix that?

Comment: This is a crucial patch for systemtap to be able to work inside a container, although as of Linux 5.10 d_real() seems to accept only first 2 arguments instead of 4. Also inode_1 is not initialized, so that needs to be taken care of.